# Set a binding programmatically for InvokeCommandAction

Tags: c#, silverlight

I can't set programmatically this binding:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=Document.MyDelegateCommandProperty}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I tried with:

```
InvokeCommandAction ica = new InvokeCommandAction();
Binding actionCommandBinding = new Binding("Document.MyDelegateCommandProperty");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(ica, InvokeCommandAction.CommandProperty, actionCommandBinding);
System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger eventTrigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger("MouseLeftButtonDown");
eventTrigger.Actions.Add(ica);
eventTrigger.Attach(myUiElement);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: what happens? do you get an error?

Comment: No error. I've put a breakpoint in the action associated with the command. In xaml version I can reach the breakpoint, in code version no.
In code version setting ica.Command = myViewModel.Document.MyDelegateCommandProperty works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used `Binding` in code but according to MSDN example for [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx) class you must set the `Binding.Source` property

```
Binding actionCommandBinding = new Binding("Document.MyDelegateCommandProperty");
actionCommandBinding.Source = ......
```

and you just passing `string` in constructor without source object/Datacontext.

Is this post was helpful for you ?

Comment: Thank you but no, a path is enough when defining the Binding().

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an old post, but since I ran into the same problem, I figured I'd post the solution.

replace 
`eventTrigger.Attach(myUiElement);`
with
`Interaction.GetTriggers(myUIElement).Add(eventTrigger);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub MapEventToCommand(eventNameSource As String, commandDestination As string)
        Dim t = New InvokeCommandAction()
        Dim commandAction As New InvokeCommandAction()
        Dim actionCommandBinding As New Binding(commandDestination)
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(commandAction, InvokeCommandAction.CommandProperty, actionCommandBinding)
        Dim eventTrigger As New EventTrigger(eventNameSource)
        eventTrigger.Actions.Add(commandAction)
        Interaction.GetTriggers(Me).Add(eventTrigger)
    End Sub
```